# Why this code is giving error.......'a' is pointer to character pointer and should store address of 's', since s is pointer to first element to array

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    char **a = &s;  //Give compilation error
    cout<<a;
}
```

Since s is a pointer to first element, I should be able to store its address in a pointer to character pointer variable..but it is showing an error.

Comment: You try to assign a `char(*)[6]` to a `char**`: When you use `&s` you get a pointer to an array which is, obviously, different from a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Since it's not clear exactly what you want to do, why you want `a` to be a pointer to a pointer to `char`, what the actual problem you try to solve is, then we can't really help you more. Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and reflect over how it relates to your question. Then [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question to be about the *real* problem.

Comment: Thanks...got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `&s` is a pointer to an object of type `char[6]` which is the type of the array `s`.

On the other hand the type `char **` is pointer type to an object of type `char *` . The types `char[6]` and `char *` are different types. So the pointer types are incompatible.

Your fallacy is that you think that in this expression `&s` the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. However such an assumption is wrong.

It is more explicitly expressed in the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators) than in the C++ Standard

> 3 **Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary
>   & operator**, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Using the array `s` can make it *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

Using plain `s` when a pointer is wanted is equal to doing `&s[0]`. That pointer will have the type `char *`. The expression `&s` is a pointer to the *array* and it will have the type `char (*)[6]`. It's very different.